# Why my thread lock failed in this situation?

Tags: python, multithreading

In every thread I want to get all data list in a recursion way by function `get_next_page_data`, when I print out the length of the specified data the expected initial param `return_data` should be `[]`

but output showed:

```
0 831
831 387
1218 1000
2218 1000
3218 529
3747 1000
4747 1000
5747 458
6205 1000
7205 1000
8205 616
8821 378
9199 188
9387 1000
10387 957
```

Why my thread lock failed in this situation?

```py
class PullCampaignDataService(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.account_token_list = self._get_account_access_token()
        self.max_worker = 5
        self.chunk_size = 10
        self.lock = threading.Lock()


    def run(self):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.max_worker) as executor:
            executor.map(self._handle_account_campaign, self.account_token_list)


    def _get_account_access_token(self):
        sql = """SELECT xxx WHERE u.status=1 AND d.status<>0"""
        return FbUser.objects.raw(sql)


    def _handle_account_campaign(self,account_token):
        account_id = account_token.account_id
        access_token = account_token.access_token

        try:
           with requests.get(
                        "https://xxxxxxxx&access_token={}" .format(
                            settings.API_VERSION, account_id, access_token))as response:
                try:
                    result_dict = json.loads(response.text)
                    campaign_list = result_dict["data"]
                except KeyError:
                    return
                try:
                    _ = result_dict["paging"]['next']
                    with self.lock:
                        next_campaign_list = self.get_next_page_data(result_dict)
                        campaign_list.extend(next_campaign_list)
                except:
                    pass

        except Exception:
            return

    def get_next_page_data(self, origin_data, return_data=[]):
        try:
            next_page_url = origin_data['paging']['next']
            with requests.get(next_page_url) as response:
                temp_ad_list = json.loads(response.text)["data"]
                print(len(return_data), len(temp_ad_list))
                return_data.extend(temp_ad_list)
                return self.get_next_page_data(json.loads(response.text))
        except KeyError:
            result = return_data
            return_data = []
            return result



PullCampaignDataService().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the lock - it is with the default parameter. It is evaluated only once - when the function definition is executed.

All your threads share one instance `return_data`.

Check a simple example:

```
def append_to_list(el, list_to_append=[]):
    list_to_append.append(el)
    return list_to_append

print(append_to_list(1))
print(append_to_list(2))
```

Comment: thanks for replying, any suggestions for me to make it?

Comment: You say you want initial value to be []. I'd use a local variable and remove the param. If you need the param in some cases, remove the default and always pass in a sensible value

Comment: Maybe, but I personally would be confused - thread local IMHO makes most sense if your design requires a global variable, but this global may be different in each thread (like decimal precision). Here, if I understand correctly, you want a recursive function with an accumulator. If you can avoid the thread local, try to do so.